# Is there a way how to use forEach for two arrays in one fixture - Cypress/Js

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I am writing automated test in Cypress and I would like help with forEach loop.
I use a fixture **people.json** where i have:

```
{
  "boys": [Peter, John, Martin,...],
  "girls": [Jessica, Jeniffer, Kim,... ]
}
```

Right now I use this forEach loop:

```
requiredFixture.boys.forEach((boy) => {
...     
}
```

So like this my test is performed for each boy from "boys" in my fixture. What I want to do is use this loop not only for boys but also for girls together (for each people). Another thing I need to do is make a condition in my test so I can get a different result depends on wheter the current people is from "boys" or "girls".

I appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance

Comment: if the arrays are the same length, I guess you could use the second argument to the callback to index into the other array

Comment: Thank you, but the fields can have different lengths

Answer (score 1):

One way (probably not the best, certainly not the ONLY way)

```
[
    ...requiredFixture.boys.map(boy => ({ boy })),
    ...requiredFixture.girls.map(girl => ({ girl }))
].forEach(({ boy, girl }) => {
    const name = boy || girl;
    // do common things with name
    if (boy) {
        // do boy only things
    }
    if (girl) {
        // do girl only things
    }
}
```